# ng-src executing even if hidden by ng-if

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here's an example for my problem. (This is a simplified version, so it may contain typos...)

---

```
# index.html

<div ng-if="testIfThereIsAnImageToDisplay">
  <img ng-src="{{url}}" imgOnLoad/>
</div>

<span ng-show="imgHasError">Your image has an error</span>
```

So, I have an image contained into a block.

I detect an error through the **imgOnLoad** directive. This part works well. Each time the **ng-src** returns a 404 (Or w/e error), I set the **imgHasError** variable to true. And my span is shown.

This is the correct behaviour I wanted.

---

But, even if the **ng-if** test fails (Because there is no image to display), Angular tries to load the content of the **ng-src**.

This results in a error on the image. So **imgHasError** is true. And then my **span** is shown.

---

Is there a way to avoid Angular to load the images hidden by a **ng-if** ?

---

**EDIT** My bad guys. I didn't realise that I was trying to display the same image in another part of my page. It comes from there. Sorry. :)

Comment: they aren't hidden, the DOM for element isn't even constructed, can you show more of your code or make working plunker/jsfiddle?

Comment: FYI: `ng-if` don't hide elements instead it clone and removes it from the DOM for later use. So thats why it loads the image so if `testIfThereIsAnImageToDisplay` become true it will simply add it back to the DOM

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs ng-if removes parts of the DOM if the condition is evaluated to false. There is a possibility that DOM is being loaded then evaluated to true/false. ng-switch, in comparison, do not event load the DOM if the condition is evaluated to false. Try ng-switch instead of ng-if.

Answer (score 0):

please see here http://jsbin.com/mupegaha/1/edit?html,js,output 
Image is not loading at all.

Double check your testIfThereIsAnImageToDisplay value

Answer (score 0):

You can set the condition in the `ng-src`: `condition && srcifconditiontrue : srcifconditionfalse`

The url if condition is false could be just `''`.

```
# index.html

<div>
  <img ng-src="{{testIfThereIsAnImageToDisplay() && url || urlerror}}" imgOnLoad/>
</div>

<span ng-show="imgHasError">Your image has an error</span>
```